# Как написать корректный тест на калькулятор JS

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, jest

Калькулятор делает простые операции, но еще умеет работать с римскими числами. Суть в том чтобы выводить информацию о всех значениях динамически в лог. По типу

> Test №1 Не пройден. Проверьте сложение арабских чисел. На выход была подана строка: `1 + 1` Ожидаемый результат: `2` Полученный результат: `null`

Пока тест выглядит так:

```js
test('должен работать с десятичными числами (сложение)', () => {
  expect(calculator('1 + 1')).toBe('2')
  expect(calculator('1 + 2')).toBe('3')
  expect(calculator('4 + 3')).toBe('7')
  expect(calculator('10 + 10')).toBe('20')
})

test('должен работать с десятичными числами (вычитание)', () => {
  expect(calculator('10 - 1')).toBe('9')
  expect(calculator('5 - 4')).toBe('1')
  expect(calculator('4 - 4')).toBe('0')
  expect(calculator('1 - 10')).toBe('-9')
  expect(calculator('4 - 5')).toBe('-1')
})
```

А хотелось бы чтобы он выводил как в примере выше с описанием того, что было подано и тд
Код калькулятора +- такой:

```js
function calculator(str) {
  const split = str.split(" ");
  const str1 = split[0];
  const str2 = split[2];
  const op = split[1];
  if(split.length != 3)
    throw new Error("Incorrect");
  const number1 = +str1;
  const number2 = +str2;
  if(!isNaN(number1) && !isNaN(number2)) {
      if(!Number.isInteger(number1) || !Number.isInteger(number2))
        throw new Error("Incorrect");
      if(number1 < 1 || number1 > 10 || number2 < 1 || number2 > 10)
        throw new Error("Incorrect");
      return calculate(number1, number2, op);
  } else if(isNaN(number1) && isNaN(number2)) {
    const rom1 = roman2arabic(str1);
    const rom2 = roman2arabic(str2);
    if(rom1 < 1 || rom1 > 10 || rom2 < 1 || rom2 > 10)
      throw new Error("Incorrect");
    const result = calculate(rom1, rom2, op);
    if(result > 0)
      return arabic2roman(result);
    else if(result < 1)
      return "";
  }
  throw new Error("Incorrect");
}

function calculate(num1, num2, oprt) {
  switch (oprt) {
    case "+":
      return String(Math.trunc(num1 + num2));
    case "-":
      return String(Math.trunc(num1 - num2));
    case "*":
      return String(Math.trunc(num1 * num2));
    case "/":
      return String(Math.trunc(num1 / num2));
    default:
      throw new Error("Incorrect");
  }
}

const digits = {
  C: 100,
  XC: 90,
  L: 50,
  XL: 40,
  X: 10,
  IX: 9,
  V: 5,
  IV: 4,
  I: 1,
};

function roman2arabic(str) {
  if(!/^[IVXLCDMZ]+$/i.test(str))
    throw new Error("Incorrect roman number format: " + str);
  return str
    .toUpperCase()
    .split("")
    .reduce(function (r, v, i, arr) {
      const [a, b, c] = [
        digits[arr[i]],
        digits[arr[i + 1]],
        digits[arr[i + 2]],
      ];
      if (b && c && a <= b && b < c)
        throw new Error("Incorrect roman number format: " + str);
      return b > a ? r - a : r + a;
    }, 0);
}

function arabic2roman(num) {
  if(!/^\-?\d+$/.test(num + ""))
    throw new Error("Can`t convert that arabic numeric to roman: " + num);
    if(num < 1)
      return "";
    let result = "";
    for (let key in digits)
      while (num >= digits[key]) {
        result += key;
        num -= digits[key];
      }
    return result;
}

module.exports = calculator
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую каждое отдельное выполнение функции `calculator` сделать отдельным тест-кейсом. Чтобы группировать тест-кейсы, использовал конструкцию [`describe()`](https://jestjs.io/ru/docs/api#describename-fn) и [`test.each()`](https://jestjs.io/ru/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout). Обратите внимание, вызовы `describe` можно вкладывать друг в друга.

```js
describe('работа с десятичными числами', () => {
  describe('сложение', () => {
    test.each`
      expr | expected
      ${'1 + 1'} | ${'2'}
      ${'1 + 2'} | ${'3'}
      ${'4 + 3'} | ${'7'}
      ${'10 + 10'} | ${'20'}
    `('результат $expr должен быть равен $expected', ({expr, expected}) => {
      expect(calculator(expr)).toBe(expected)
    });
  });
  describe('вычитание', () => {
    test.each`
      expr | expected
      ${'10 - 1'} | ${'9'}
      ${'5 - 4'} | ${'1'}
      ${'4 - 4'} | ${'0'}
      ${'1 - 10'} | ${'-9'}
      ${'4 - 5'} | ${'-1'}
    `('результат $expr должен быть равен $expected', ({expr, expected}) => {
      expect(calculator(expr)).toBe(expected)
    });
  });
});

describe('работа с римскими числами', () => {
  //...
});
```

Вот что получается на выходе:

```
 PASS  ru-so/calculator.test.js
  работа с десятичными числами
    сложение
      √ результат 1 + 1 должен быть равен 2 (2 ms)
      √ результат 1 + 2 должен быть равен 3 (1 ms)
      √ результат 4 + 3 должен быть равен 7
      √ результат 10 + 10 должен быть равен 20
    вычитание
      √ результат 10 - 1 должен быть равен 9
      √ результат 5 - 4 должен быть равен 1
      √ результат 4 - 4 должен быть равен 0
      √ результат 1 - 10 должен быть равен -9 (4 ms)
      √ результат 4 - 5 должен быть равен -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test('должен работать с римскими числами (сложение)', () => {`введите сюда код`
  expect(calculator('I + I')).toBe('II');
  expect(calculator('I + II')).toBe('III');
  expect(calculator('IV + III')).toBe('VII');
  expect(calculator('X + X')).toBe('XX');
  expect(calculator('X + IX')).toBe('XIX');
});

test('должен работать с римскими числами (вычитание)', () => {
  expect(calculator('X - I')).toBe('IX');
  expect(calculator('V - IV')).toBe('I');
  expect(calculator('IV - IV')).toBe('');
  expect(calculator('I - X')).toBe('');
  expect(calculator('IV - V')).toBe('');
});

test('должен работать с римскими числами (умножение)', () => {
  expect(calculator('X * X')).toBe('C');
  expect(calculator('IV * X')).toBe('XL');
  expect(calculator('V * I')).toBe('V');
  expect(calculator('V * V')).toBe('XXV');
});

test('должен работать с римскими числами (деление)', () => {
  expect(calculator('X / I')).toBe('X');
  expect(calculator('VI / II')).toBe('III');
  expect(calculator('V / IV')).toBe('I');
  expect(calculator('II / IV')).toBe('');
});

test('должен выбрасывать ошибку на некорректных данных', () => {
  expect(() => calculator('')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator(' ')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('     ')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('4')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('+')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('++1')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('V')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('3 % 4')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('1 + 1 + 1')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('11 + 1')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('1 + 11')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('XI + I')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('I + XI')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('1 + V')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('I + 1')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('5 / 0')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('0 + 1')).toThrowError();
  expect(() => calculator('1 + 0')).toThrowError();
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]